# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when closing a material-ui modal by setting state

Tags: reactjs, axios, material-ui

So I used the modal component from material-UI and use an "open" state hook to control its visibility. Within this component, I created a Login page component, which would post the information using Axios and set the open state to false, so that the modal is closed. After I clicked the log-in button, the console reports

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.

Here is my code:

```
function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    AxiosInstance
        .post("/api/token/", account)
        .then((res)=>{
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            AxiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('access_token');
            console.log(res);
            props.setOpen(false);
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just solve this problem by using a flag so that the state is changed outside of Axios's get request.

```
function handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const flag = false;
    AxiosInstance
        .post("/api/token/", account)
        .then((res)=>{
            localStorage.setItem('access_token', res.data.access);
            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', res.data.refresh);
            AxiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem('access_token');
            history.push("/#");
            history.push("/home");
            console.log(res);
            flag = true;
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            
        })
        
    if (flag)
        props.setOpen(false);
}
```

However, I still don't understand how Axios work. It seems that all state changes are better not put in asyn function to me.

Comment: That's the way async functions work. Initially, you put it inside **then()** which occurs once the promise resolved. But with later implementation, it occurs after the async function invoked and it won't wait until the promise resolved. That's why previous error didn't happen at the 2nd time.